# Generalize Jenkins Pipeline script with PR Process for branches of same/different repos

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Working on PR process using Pull Request Notifier for Bit bucket plug-in for Pipeline Jobs. Thanks to the excellent write-up from [here](https://dengelonsoftware.blogspot.com/2017/01/jenkins-pull-request-and-pipeline.html)

Its a common pipeline script "JenkinsFile" available in SCM. Leveraging on the same script and trying to enhance further

```
node {        
    stage('Checkout') {
        def description = "<a href='$PULL_REQUEST_URL'>PR #$PULL_REQUEST_ID</a>"
        currentBuild.setDescription(description)        
        checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm:
        [
            $class: 'GitSCM',           
            branches: [
                [name: PULL_REQUEST_FROM_HASH ]
            ],
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
            extensions: [
                [$class: 'PreBuildMerge',  
                options: [ 
                        mergeStrategy: 'MergeCommand.Strategy', 
                        fastForwardMode: 'NO_FF', 
                        mergeRemote: 'origin', 
                        mergeTarget: PULL_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH
                    ]
                ]],
            userRemoteConfigs: 
            [[
                credentialsId: '232272334-4f2a-47f8-8387-401fc2c5500a', 
                url: 'ssh://git@remoteUrl/develop/entity-web.git'
            ]]
        ]
    }

    // ... multiple stages of build
}
```

The above script work excellent if the Source and Target branches falls in same Project Key and repo name. i.e any feature/bugfix/custom branches are in same URL.
From `"develop/entity-web(entity-featureName, branch cut from master)" to develop/entity-web(master)`

Now if PR can be from different Projects. i.e from Source branch `"develop/entity-web(master)" to "release/entity-web(master)"`. The above script fails

The issue facing now is

1) Have a commit in `"develop/entity-web(master)"`

2) Create an PR from `"develop/entity-web(master)" to "release/entity-web(master)"`.

3) The PR gets triggered from Bit bucket and Jenkins Job gets triggered with build with Parameters like "http://localhost:8080/job/JobName/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&cause=PULL_REQUEST&PULL_REQUEST_URL=http://localhost:7990/projects/release/entity-web/pull-requests/1&PULL_REQUEST_ID=1&PULL_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH=master&PULL_REQUEST_FROM_HASH=6d1a252fa28c765846ba5dfc1f819bb0769ce4d9"

4) The above script tries to find the commit Hash `"6d1a252fa28c765846ba5dfc1f819bb0769ce4d9"` in `release/entity-web`. But the commit is in `develop/entity-web(master)`. 
So the GIT checkout fails.

> git rev-parse 6d1a252fa28c765846ba5dfc1f819bb0769ce4d9^{commit} # timeout=10
>   git rev-parse origin/6d1a252fa28c765846ba5dfc1f819bb0769ce4d9^{commit} # timeout=10
>   git rev-parse 6d1a252fa28c765846ba5dfc1f819bb0769ce4d9^{commit} # timeout=10.

Similar problems you will have with Fork branches to master.

Any help in generalized script where the source and target can be from same/different repos??.